# Writing in Latin on Windows

Tags: latin-on-devices

Inspired by [this question from Joonas Ilmavirta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/writing-in-latin-on-an-android-phone), and the seemingly great response, I have decided to ask about a relevant operating system in my life: Windows. I have long detested the red squiggly lines under my Latin text in Microsoft Office. :) I have made slight progress with Word, for which I found a proofing language download for Latin, but it worked very poorly.

Any assistance on this front would be interesting to hear about, and it does not have to be a complete solution. Even if it is a proofing language for Word, I would be glad to hear about it!

---

It does not appear as if these types of questions have been deemed off-topic yet, but this is of course subject to change.

Comment: Would it be better to separate the two systems in different questions? Or do you expect that the same answers will be typically equally valid for both?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I am just not expecting much of a response for the Apple side of things, and I don't want to clutter up the questions with a bunch of these types, so we will see what happens.

Comment: True, it might be too much to ask many questions of this kind in one or two days. I sometimes plan questions in advance and spread the possibly controversial ones out. While there might not be many answers for Apple, it would still make sense as a separate question. Having a clear but unanswered question might attract the right kind of attention at some point. // I think we should really have a question about Latin spellcheckers for computers, including Word. I'm more satisfied with Latin on my phone than on my computer.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I agree that this should be split up in two: Word and iOS are different cans of worms!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I will limit the question to just Windows then, as that is more pressing of the two in my opinion

Comment: I know how to deal with this on the Mac, if that's helpful.

Comment: Shoudn’t the question be : *Writing in Latin on MS Word*, or better in *MS Word or LibreOffice* in order to have a more general question?

Comment: Furthermore, concerning the question, I just founded this with a simple search: http://drouizig.org/index.php/en/binviou-en/correttore-ortografico-di-latino/250-en-col-latin-spellchecker

However I haven’t tested it as I don’t own any MS Word license.

Answer (score 4):

#### LibreOffice

If you want spellchecking for Latin, someone's made a pretty decent LibreOffice [Latin spellcheck dictionary](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/latin-spelling-and-hyphenation-dictionaries).  And LibreOffice works on Linux, Window, and Mac, is open source, free, and awesome, so you should have it anyways.

After you install [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/), follow these instructions to install the [Latin spellcheck dictionary](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/latin-spelling-and-hyphenation-dictionaries):

> In LibreOffice, select Tools --> Extension Manager from the menu bar.
>
> In the Extension Manager dialog click Add.
>
> A file browser window opens. Navigate to the folder where you saved the LibreOffice
>   extension file(s) on your system. The extension's files have the file
>   extension 'OXT'.
>
> Find and select the extension you want to install and
>   click Open.
>
> If this extension is already installed, you'll be prompted
>   to press OK to confirm whether to overwrite the current version by the
>   new one, or press Cancel to stop the installation.
>
> After you are asked
>   whether to install the extension only for your user or for all users.
>   If you choose the Only for me option, the extension will be installed
>   only for your user. If you choose For all users, you need system
>   administrator rights. In this case the extension will be available for
>   all users. In general, choose Only for me, that doesn't require
>   administration rights on the operating system.

After this, in your document, go to **Tools > Language > For Selection > More...**, and in the **Language** box select *Latin*.

#### If you really want to use Word...

In Word 2003, you were able to go to **Tools > Language** and change the document language to Latin.  It didn't do any spell checking, but hey, you got a little 'Latin' label in the bottom right instead of 'English' (or whatever language you use).

It appears they've stripped a bunch of the language options out of more recent versions of Word.  To stop spellcheck, under Tools > Language you can always change it to a language that you don't have a spellcheck dictionary for (Latvian sounds close enough).  Or you can check the box that says *Do not check spelling or grammar*.

Of course, if you want to be really geeky, you can always use Vim...